# spawn many monsters ( imageViews )

Tags: objective-c

I am programming a small game and I have a UFO at the top of the view as a imageView which is moving left to right. Now I would like to let the big Ufo spawn some little Ufos at a random time. The random part is no problem for me, but I don't know how to spawn the small ones. I could make a 100 Outlets and images and hide them first, but there must be an easier method for that? After spawning the little UFO's have to move and be able to have an collision with my character. But first, I would like to spawn them :).

I'd be happy if u can help me!

Kind Regards,

Robin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create image views programatically like this:

```
UIImageView *image =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,20,20)];
myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

Then you can put this in a loop to generate many image views

Answer (score 1):

Spawn them programatically.

Let's say you have a function that is called every "random-number"-second.

In the function body:

- Create an instance of a UIImageView
- Set an appropriate position to the imageView
- Set the image on the image view
- Add that instance as a subview to your view

That's the spawning part.

In order to the able to use them later:

- Add the instance to an array (could be called "childUfos" or something)
- Iterate over the array in order to move or interact with the ufos
- When a child ufo dies/goes out of screen, remove it from the array

Comment: My Ufo's are spawning and falling in the direction to the ground now, but they stop moving when the next one is spawned! I hope you can help me!

I don't know how to change it with the array. I would suggest a mutable array, but i don't know how to add it and how to use the ufos then. Here is my Code.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/417a80f38f5ac26d3804

Comment: The code you posted does not reflect my proposal. Create a new instance of a UIImageView, add that instance to an array. You're currently overwriting the ufo

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1d108b07d1047ef8299

its spawning 1 UFO now and then i get an error Signal SignalBRT. I think there is something wrong with the index, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I made an exception breakpoint and it stops in the Line where i access to the array : 
`UIImageView *newUfo = [self.Ufos objectAtIndex:(-1+indexOfUfos)];`

it spawns one UFO and then it stops when trying to spawn the next one. I don't understand why and I'd be happy if u can help me. Maybe something with the adding Ufos to the array is wrong?

Comment: okay, so I made some NSLogs and tested something and I think, the length of the array is not increasing somehow. Can you help me ? :)